# SQL Server - DECLARE SET is taking too much time to execute than hardcoding the parameters in where condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, common-table-expression, declare

I have a simple select statement of a CTE where I have Declared and SET values before the WITH and I'm fetching data for a single day which would be having nearly 200,000 rows of data. If I execute that query, it is taking more time(not completed in 10 minutes). But If I remove those DECLARE, SET and hardcoded those input values in WHERE condition, the results are shown in 15 SECONDS.

This table has nearly 350 million rows of data with Proper Indexing of Primary Key columns.

What could be the possibility of this slowness?

**Actual Query**

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @ApplicationName VARCHAR(100)
SET @StartTime = '2018-12-10'
SET @EndTime = '2018-12-10'
SET @Applicationname = 'APPNAME'

;WITH TOTAL as (
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME >= + @StartTime + '00:00:01' AND
DATETIME <= + @EndTime + '23:59:59'
AND APPLICATIONID=(SELECT APPLICATIONID FROM APPLICATION WHERE ApplicationName=@Applicationname 
)
SELECT * FROM TOTAL
```

**After Change**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME >= '2018-12-10 00:00:01' AND
DATETIME <= '2018-12-10 23:59:59'
AND APPLICATIONID=(SELECT APPLICATIONID FROM APPLICATION WHERE ApplicationName='APPNAME'
```

Actually the DB has an SP with Long query, here I have provided the first CTE table only and the same kind of table conditions applicable to my rest of the CTE tables. If I get a clue for this slowness, I would fix the rest of my queries.

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing, where a sub-optimal execution plan is created. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Try to add option(recompile) to a problem statement and if it hels it's parameter sniffing as was pointed out by Dale Burrell

Comment: Can you post the actual plans for both queries to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: These are variables not parameters. Variables are not sniffed. And that is likely the problem as SQL Server then can't get accurate estimates of number of rows that will match. `option(recompile)` will help for that too

Comment: Use **select * from table with(nolock)**  keyword for a lot of transaction and performance.

Comment: @hsyn.ozkara I used with(nolock) as well. But still the same performance issue.

Comment: No - don't use nolock as some magic "go faster" technique without understading the consequences. Simply **bad advice**.

Comment: It is difficult to help you identify performance problems with a "sample" query that makes little sense and is syntactically invalid. I suggest that it is also logically flawed but whether that will affect your results cannot be known. For a given date, your actual upper and lower boundaries can exclude values that should be included due to your precision assumptions. And why you feel it necessary to set the variables to just dates and then add the time portions makes little sense as well - and perhaps complicates things.

Comment: Tibor discusses in **great detail** the datetime datatype, common flaws in usage, and recommended ways to search for values [here](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks for the help. After putting WITH RECOMPILE in the query, the execution time reduced to 2 minutes which is much more lesser than the initial (~more than 10 Minutes). Since the table has more ~350 million rows of data, I believe we should expect this 2 minutes execution time?

Answer (score -2):

Since SQL server have to compile the variables StartTime and EndTime for each record on the TABLE for filtering, it takes longer. if you do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
DECLARE @ApplicationName VARCHAR(100)
SET @StartTime = '2018-12-10 00:00:01'
SET @EndTime = '2018-12-10 23:59:59'
SET @Applicationname = 'APPNAME'

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATETIME >= @StartTime AND DATETIME <= @EndTime
AND APPLICATIONID=(SELECT APPLICATIONID FROM APPLICATION WHERE 
ApplicationName=@Applicationname
```

By doing this, you are reducing the load at the filtering time and doing pre-computing the required fixed variables.